# How can I merge two arrays of strings into all possible strings to share open username options? (user_name, username, _username, etc.)

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to suggest usernames for users who chose a username that's already taken.

How can I suggest all possible combinations of their name with various underscore combinations?

```
function username_options($name) {
    $spacers = array('_','');
    $username_options_array = array();
    // how can I iterate through all combinations no matter how many
    // words are included in the name?
    // ex. joesmith, _joesmith, _joe_smith, _joe_smith_
    //     joe_smith, joe_smith_,
    //     joesmith_
}

$names = array('joe smith','alan beta gamma','albert beta gamma delta');
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $username_options_array = username_options($name);
    print_r($username_options_array);
}
```

Merging two strings like `joe smith` is easy enough:

```
$a . $b
$a . '_' . $b
$a . $b . '_'
'_' . $a . $b
'_' . $a . $b . '_'
'_' . $a . '_' . $b . '_'
```

But how can I do this more elegantly with `n` number of strings in a name? So `alan beta gamma delta` would populate as easily as `joe smith`?

Comment: does the `$spacers` always contains  `array('_','')` or it can contain 3 elemnts or more ?

Comment: @Khalid, just those two. What do you have in mind?

Comment: You could use `String.split()` to put the username into a an array and then parse through all options with a loop.  Let me know if I need to be more specific.

Comment: @BRad, yes. I'm struggling with how to loop through all of the combinations. I can do two, but not `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a function that returns all the combinations of your spacers depending on how many places are you going to put your spaces.

```
function everyCombination($count,$len) 
{
    $elems = pow($count,$len);
    $result = [];
    for($i=0;$i<$elems;$i++)
        $result[] = str_pad(base_convert($i,10,$count),$len,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return $result;
}
```

Now this function returns all the combination of indexes of your spacers array, all you need to do is to explode your string (`$name`) by spaces to combine the spacers with indexes with the array of name after exploding it.

```
function username_options($name) 
{
    $spacers = array('_','');
    $result = [];
    $words = explode(' ', $name);
    $combinations = everyCombination(count($spacers),count($words)+1);
    foreach ($combinations as $combin) 
    {
        $str = $words[] = "";
        for($i=0;$i<strlen($combin);$i++)
            $str .= $spacers[$combin[$i]] . $words[$i];
        $result[] = $str;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

now after testing this

```
$names = array('joe smith','alan beta gamma');
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $username_options_array = username_options($name);
    var_dump($username_options_array);
}
```

I get as result this :

```
array (size=8)
  0 => string '_joe_smith_' (length=11)
  1 => string '_joe_smith' (length=10)
  2 => string '_joesmith_' (length=10)
  3 => string '_joesmith' (length=9)
  4 => string 'joe_smith_' (length=10)
  5 => string 'joe_smith' (length=9)
  6 => string 'joesmith_' (length=9)
  7 => string 'joesmith' (length=8)
array (size=16)
  0 => string '_alan_beta_gamma_' (length=17)
  1 => string '_alan_beta_gamma' (length=16)
  2 => string '_alan_betagamma_' (length=16)
  3 => string '_alan_betagamma' (length=15)
  4 => string '_alanbeta_gamma_' (length=16)
  5 => string '_alanbeta_gamma' (length=15)
  6 => string '_alanbetagamma_' (length=15)
  7 => string '_alanbetagamma' (length=14)
  8 => string 'alan_beta_gamma_' (length=16)
  9 => string 'alan_beta_gamma' (length=15)
  10 => string 'alan_betagamma_' (length=15)
  11 => string 'alan_betagamma' (length=14)
  12 => string 'alanbeta_gamma_' (length=15)
  13 => string 'alanbeta_gamma' (length=14)
  14 => string 'alanbetagamma_' (length=14)
  15 => string 'alanbetagamma' (length=13)
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly! Thanks.